# Wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) - ArgumentError in CommerceController#receive

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Reacquainting myself with rails after some hiatus, I can't figure out why I get the following error when trying to render the page locally on my browser, after generating a new controller with two actions.

```rb
Wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) - ArgumentError in CommerceController#receive
```

This is the new controller and actions:

`rails g controller Commerce send receive`

Nothing too fancy in either the controller and views sections:

app/controllers/commerce_controller.rb

```rb
class CommerceController < ApplicationController

  layout false

  def send
  end

  def receive
  end

end
```

views/commerce/receive.html.erb

```rb
<h1>Coronavirus Coachella Cure</h1>
```

routes.rb

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'demo#index'

  get 'commerce/send'

  get 'commerce/receive'

end
```

I try to view the page on my browser by accessing http://localhost:3000/commerce/receive or http://localhost:3000/commerce/send

The error points to 'def send' line in app/controllers/commerce_controller.rb.

What's causing this error that causes the page not to render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite `Object#send` Ruby method, name your action differently.